# Flask/uWSGI throws error unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='')

Tags: python, uwsgi

Im trying to run (just for testing purposes):

```
uwsgi --socket 0.0.0.0:8000 --protocol=http -w wsgi_prod
```

**from a dir with:**

```
home.py
home.pyc
wsgi_prod.py
wsgi_prod.pyc
```

**my `wsgi_prod.py` has:**

```
from home import app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

**`home.py` has:**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from jinja2 import Template

app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='static')

@app.route('/')
def home():
    print('Hello world')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

When I run it, it throws:

```
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
*** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (and the only)
```

What am I doing wrong? Why cant it see my app?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I hope this helps someone out someday. Digital Ocean offers a great article to setup your flask/uwsgi, but offers the wrong command for this.

Use this instead:

```
uwsgi --socket 0.0.0.0:8000 --protocol=http -w wsgi_prod:app
```

and use this [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04)